# I can be cold, I can be hot, I can be hanging, I can be standing, and I have a head. Many enjoy taking me. What am I?

Tags: riddle

This is my English adaptation of a popular riddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> a shower

although

> I don't think I've heard the words "hanging" and "standing" apply to showers -- though it seems to me they easily could.

Comment: wow. this is the correct answer :) I do not know how to better adapt the riddle to English. In the original language, it makes perfect sense and even rhymes.

Comment: To me, 'hanging' and 'standing' could be interpreted as rot13(zrnaf bs nggnpuvat gurz gb onguebbz svkgherf (n syrkvoyr ubfr be jnyy-zbhagrq bhgyrg, naq n fbyvq iregvpny cvcr, sbe rknzcyr)). I wonder if that is the usage in the original language?

Comment: For what it's worth, that's more or less what I assumed was meant by the terms here.